Transit visa to Qatar (layover for 2 hours only)
I'm a Filipino passport holder, and I'm travelling from the UK to Philippines. My question is do I need a transit visa to Doha International Airport to catch my next flight to the Philippines? I'm with my child also. Please help me (for emergency travel proposes).

What is your country of residence? Which airline(s) are you travelling with?

No, you don't need a transit visa for Qatar. According to official statement, Qatar Airways passengers transiting in Hamad International Airport for a minimum of 5 hours are eligible to apply for the Qatar Transit Visa. It is free of charge, valid for up to 96 hours (four days) and open to passengers of all nationalities.

The OP doesn’t say they are travelling on Qatar Airways. If they’re not, the site you link to says a Filipino citizen needs a visa (A3 or A1)

Here is another link (https://www.dohaguides.com/transit-visa-for-qatar/) that suggests that you do not need to have a transit visa (regardless of airline), if the entire trip is on a single ticket.

The OP doesn’t say they’ll be travelling on a single ticket either. You should expand your answer to cover the possible transit scenarios, or wait to answer until the OP provides clarification.

To be clear: this answer is only correct if the OP is traveling on a single ticket (one PNR), via Qatar Airways, and has a transit time of five hours or more. If any of those three conditions are not satisfied, then this answer is incorrect and the OP needs a visa.
